# trying to validate user input in php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to validate user input in php. This code will check if the values are null or not. If it is null, this will require the user to input the values that are null. When all the text boxes in the html form that came before this. This code will show the submit button, and that submit button will save the inputted data into the mysql database. But the problem is that the value that is saved is zero zero and zero, what might be the cause of this?

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Admission Information Sheet</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; Western (ISO-8859-1)">
    <meta name="author" content=" ">
<title>
<style>
input { font-size: 16px;}
</style>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<div id="main_content">

</div>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>

<table border="1" width="900" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1.1" method="POST" action="aisaction.php">

<?php
 $NURSE = $_POST[nurse];
     $TELNUM = $_POST[telnum];
     $HOSPNUM = $_POST[hnum];
     $ROOMNUM = $_POST[rnum];
     $LASTNAME = $_POST[lname];
     $FIRSTNAME = $_POST[fname];
     $MIDNAME = $_POST[mname];
     $AD = $_POST[ad];


     $ADATE = $_POST[adate];
     $ADTIME = $_POST[adtime];
     $CSTAT = $_POST[cs];
     $AGE = $_POST[age];
     $BDAY = $_POST[bday];
     $SEX = $_POST[sex];


     ?>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="12" style="background:#9ACD32; color:white; border:white 1px solid; text-align: center"><strong><font size="3">ADMISSION INFORMATION SHEET</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>


</td><br>     
<td width="54"><font size="3">Hospital #</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="168"><input type="display" name="hnum" disabled="true" value= "<?php print "$HOSPNUM";?>"><br>
         <font color="red">     
     <?php   
        if(empty($HOSPNUM))
            print "* Hospital Number required!<br>";
    ?>
</td>

<td width="41"><font size="3">Room #</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="168"><input type="display" name="rnum" disabled="true" value= "<?php print "$ROOMNUM";?>"><br>
        <font color="red">      
     <?php
            if(empty($ROOMNUM))
            print "* Room Number required!<br>";
     ?>
</td>

<td width="67"><font size="3">Admission Date</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="168"><input type="display" name="adate" disabled="true" value= "<?php print "$ADATE";?>"><br>
        <font color="red">      
     <?php
            if(empty($ADATE))
            print "* Admission Date required!<br>";
     ?>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td><font size="3">Last Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="display" name="lname" disabled="true" value= "<?php print "$LASTNAME";?>"><br>
        <font color="red">      
     <?php
            if(empty($LASTNAME))
            print "* Last Name required!<br>";
     ?>
</td>
<td><font size="3">First Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="display" name="fname" disabled="true" value= "<?php print "$FIRSTNAME";?>"><br>
        <font color="red">      
     <?php
            if(empty($FIRSTNAME))
            print "* First Name required!<br>";
     ?>
</td>
<td><font size="3">Middle Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="display" name="mname" disabled="true" value= "<?php print "$MIDNAME";?>"><br>
        <font color="red">      
     <?php
            if(empty($MIDNAME))
            print "* Middle Name required!<br>";
     ?>
</td>
<td><font size="3">Admit time</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="display" name="mname" disabled="true" value= "<?php print "$ADTIME";?>"><br>
        <font color="red">      
     <?php
            if(empty($ADTIME))
            print "* Adtime  required!<br>";
     ?>
</td>
</tr>



<tr>
<td><font size="3">Civil Status</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="display" name="cs" disabled="true" value= "<?php print "$CSTAT";?>"><br>
        <font color="red">      
     <?php
            if(empty($CSTAT))
            print "* Civil Status required!<br>";
     ?>
</td>
<td><font size="3">Age</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="display" name="age" disabled="true" value= "<?php print "$AGE";?>"><br>
        <font color="red">      
     <?php
            if(empty($AGE))
            print "* Age required!<br>";
     ?>
</td>
<td><font size="3">Birthday</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="display" name="bday" disabled="true" value= "<?php print "$BDAY";?>"><br>
        <font color="red">      
     <?php
            if(empty($BDAY))
            print "* Birthday required!<br>";
     ?>
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><font size="3">Address</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="display" name="address" disabled="true" value= "<?php print "$AD";?>"><br>
        <font color="red">      
     <?php
            if(empty($AD))
            print "* Address required!<br>";
     ?>
</td>
<td><font size="3">Telephone #</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="display" name="telnum" disabled="true" value= "<?php print "$TELNUM";?>"></td>

<td width="23"><font size="3">Sex</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="174"><input type="display" name="sex" disabled="true" value= "<?php print "$SEX";?>"><br>
        <font color="red">      
     <?php
            if(empty($SEX))
            print "* Gender required!<br>";
     ?>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><font size="3">Pls. Check</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="stats1" type="checkbox" id="SSS" value="SSS">SSS</td>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="stats1" type="checkbox" id="nonmed" value="NonMedicare">Non Medicare</td>

<td><font size="3"></td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="stats1" type="checkbox" id="sh" value="stockholder">Stockholder</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<td><input name="stats1" type="checkbox" id="gsis" value="GSIS">GSIS</td>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<td><input name="stats1" type="checkbox" id="senior" value="seniorcitizen">Senior-Citizen</td>


<tr>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<td><input name="stats1" type="checkbox" id="dep" value="dependent">Dependent</td>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<td><input name="stats1" type="checkbox" id="emp" value="employee">Employee</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><font size="3">Attending Nurse</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="display" name="nurse" disabled="true" value= "<?php print "$NURSE";?>"><br>
        <font color="red">      
     <?php
            if(empty($NURSE))
            print "* Admitting/Attending Nurse required!<br>";
     ?>
</td>


</tr>


<tr>

<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>

<td><input type="button" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">
<?php
        $val1 = $_POST['NURSE'];
        if($_POST['NURSE'] !="")
        {
    ?>
    <form action="aisaction.php" method="POST" target="_window">
            <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="yes">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
        }
    ?>

</td>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
</td>


</form>
</tr>
</table>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, try to reduce your error to the simplest possible case. People can't spend 10 minutes in reading all of your code. In this specific example, try to perform the same action with one parameter only and paste just the relevant code, not the whole page. This will help you in receiving much more answers.

Comment: Also, please provide the code that inserts the data into the database and the database schema for the table that stores the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I usually deal with forms and validations in PHP. I'm not going to re-format your full code, so I'm just showing the method.

**Live example: http://kopli.pri.ee/stackoverflow/2351193.php**

**Full version of the code:***

```
<?php

function is_valid_email ($email) {
    if(!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])' . '(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+' . '(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i', $email)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if ($_POST['trigger']) {
    $p_name = $_POST['name'];
    $p_email = $_POST['email'];

    if (empty($p_name)) {$posting_errors[] = 'Name is missing!';}
    if ($p_name and strlen($p_name) < 3) {$posting_errors[] = 'Name is too short!';}
    if (empty($p_email)) {$posting_errors[] = 'Email is missing!';}
    elseif (is_valid_email($p_email)) {$posting_errors[] = 'Email is incorrect!';}

    if ($posting_errors) {
        $posting_message = '<div class="error_message">' . implode('<br />', $posting_errors) . '</div>';
    } else {
        $posting_message = '<div class="success_message">Great success!</div>';
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>trying to validate user input in php - Kalle H. Väravas</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style>
        html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: #CCFFFF;}
        label {font-weight: bold; width: 140px; display: inline-block; padding: 5px;}
        .success_message,
        .error_message {display: inline-block; padding: 2px 5px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 5px;}
        .success_message {background: #A9F5AB;}
        .error_message {background: #FF8080;}
        #global_container {margin: 20px auto; width: 500px; padding: 20px; background: #FFFFFF;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="global_container">
        <?php echo $posting_message; ?>
        <form method="post">
            <input name="trigger" type="hidden" value="1" />
            <label>Name:</label><input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo ($_POST['name'] ? $_POST['name'] : '') ?>" /><br />
            <label>Email:</label><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo ($_POST['email'] ? $_POST['email'] : '') ?>" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it might be to actually check the value in the $_POST array using something like "isset()".

e.g.

```
if(!isset($_POST['whatever']))
```

Also, if none of your expected values can be zero then you can always add a

```
if(empty($WHATEVER)||$WHATEVER==0)
```

***p.s. as Gordon mentioned, if you provide the code you're using for inserting the info into your DB and an idea on what your DB schema is it will greatly help us give you a more exact answer

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and best way is to use jQuery Validation for forms, which will automatically validates form´s data before sending them into the server. I do like using it more then validating things in the server